# div with min-width growing with it's content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am a CSS/HTML auto learner, apologies if my question is stupid.

I want a div which is 40% wide minimum with its content justified but when more items will be added in this div its width grows accordingly.

This is what I have so far:

```
.hcontainerbutton {
    display: flex;
    width: 40%;
    background-color: blue;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    right: 30%;
    left: 30%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0!important;
}
```

both with `width:40%` or `min-width:40%` the div doesn't grow if I add more items into it

Comment: For us to be able answer properly without guessing, add a working code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Wrap `.hcontainerbutton` in a container and apply `flexbox` and `height` properties to it. This can be used to position `.hcontainerbutton` instead of `position: absolute`.
2. Add `min-width` value to `.hcontainerbutton`

You can test this layout by adding and remove `.content` divs and viewing in full screen.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.hcontainerbutton {
  min-width: 40%;
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-top: auto;
}

.content {
  background: pink;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="hcontainerbutton">
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: worked like a charm!! unfortunately I can't give any vote because of my reputation... but thanks a lot

Comment: I just have a minor issue, not sure whether it can be fixed at all. Basically your .content for me are buttons therefore I want them to have a different style on hover. Giving them a fixed width when hovering over only their width style is changed. If I give them 100% width to cover the maximum space they can leaves .hcontainerbutton always 40% wide.

Comment: @CMig I'm not exactly sure what you mean, would you be able to create a demo showing the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirements, this can be done with normal CSS itself, you need not go for flex, Here is an explanation on what is done.

First we set the width and height of `html` and `body` tag, then using `margin:0px` remove the margins set by the browser.

```
html,
body {
  width: 100% height: auto;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

Now the parent that will wrap the centered div will have to have the CSS property `text-align:center`, basically what this does is, it will center align elements with display property `inline-block`.

```
.parent {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Then coming to the main div, which has the class `hcontainerbutton`, we can set the `max-width`(in the example I use `40%`) and `min-width`(in the example I use `80%`) to whatever is needed. The CSS property `display:inline-block` ensures it takes the width of the content alone. The CSS property `word-wrap:break-word` ensures the text is broken and maintains the widht of the div.

Below is a working snippet of the code.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100% height: auto;
  margin: 0px;
}

.parent {
  text-align: center;
}

.hcontainerbutton {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  min-width: 40%;
  max-width: 80%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="hcontainerbutton"> asdf
  </div>
  <div class="hcontainerbutton"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin eleifend magna augue. Morbi sagittis eu urna et facilisis. Nam finibus erat justo, vel porta magna aliquam a. Pellentesque faucibus molestie libero vitae condimentum. Nunc condimentum tincidunt
    nulla, id suscipit magna dignissim id. Nulla dapibus suscipit velit et viverra. Mauris non gravida justo. Sed efficitur eleifend elementum. Integer non mattis mi. Etiam vestibulum viverra erat, eget dapibus tellus iaculis ut. Mauris ullamcorper magna
    sapien, ac gravida odio blandit varius. Fusce eu placerat enim. Etiam nec elementum dui. In fermentum massa sed augue interdum aliquam. Nunc lacinia blandit elit a iaculis.
  </div>
</div>
```